# How to parse x509 certificate with strange OID with openssl?

Tags: c++, openssl, x509certificate

I have certificates with the following numbers:

"1.3.14.3.2.3" szOID_OIWSEC_md5RSA

"1.2.840.113549.1.1.4" szOID_OIWSEC_shaRSA

The openssl does not parse them, says unsupported algorithm.
At the same time C# can parse such certificates from the box using class x509Certificate2.

How do I do this with openssl?

Answer (score 0):

The OIDs mentioned by you came from NIST OSE Implementors Workshop and are now considered legacy ones and not supported by OpenSSL. They seem to be supported by Microsoft API(s) for compatibility.

If you really want to work this with OpenSSL, you will have tweak OpenSSL. Check the below link:

https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a471/inserting-custom-oids-into-openssl.aspx